# Liferay Custom Login Portlet

Tags: liferay, vaadin

I'm new to liferay and was wondering if it is possible ( and how ) to create a custom login portlet using Vaadin framework .
thanks

Answer (score 1):

there is 2 ways to do this:
1.in liferay you can override custom jsp pages using [hooks](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/hoo-4), in this overrided jsp page you can include your vaadin portlet address using jsp tags, maybe you should override authenticateByScreenName/authenticateByEmailAddress(...) methods in UserLocalService (you can do this by hooks too)

2.using a [struts custom action in liferay](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/performing-a-custom-acti-4), this can be done by hooks too,I think it's better idea